# You can't specify target table 'categorylist' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I struggled with the following quite some time and I do not seem to find the right solution. Even with examples here I am not able to solve it. Could you please help me to rewrite the query to see what I have done wrong?

I will put the query based on what I try to achieve:

```
insert into categorylist (SONGID, CATEGORYID, SORTID)  
VALUES (
select songid, '784' as categoryid, sortid from categorylist
where categoryid = '781' and songid not in
(select songid from categorylist 
 where categoryid in (651, 514, 517, 731, 746,658,655,522, 525,775))
)
```

The select statement works, but when I add the insert part I got a Error 1064.

As an alternative I try to rewrite it, to update the categoryid:

```
update categorylist
set categoryid = '784'
where categoryid = '781' and songid not in 
(select songid from categorylist where categoryid in 
(651, 514, 517, 731, 746,658,655,522, 525,775))
```

Now I got an: 
errorcode 1093: You can't specify target table 'categorylist' for update in FROM clause

I have tried serveral solutions here and found elsewhere, but I can not work around it. Maybe it is not possible and is a temp db needed as stated in [You can't specify target table '' for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035495/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Thank you very much for your help.